In Slickgrid,an empty row is displayed while hiding the column which is used for aggregate function
I am using angular slick grid version 4.3.1 to show my list of data. As per configurtion, aggregate function calculation is happening for column while data is grouped based on a field.
1. After that If I hide the field which is used for aggregate function and an empty row is displayed(where an aggregate function result had displayed).
2. If we group the morethan one fields with and without aggregate function configuration.The result of aggregate function result is confusing to the end user.
Steps to Reproduce :

Aggregate function is configured for fees field while grouping gender field.After grouping gender field,aggregate function result of fees field is displayed in last row.After that If I hide the fees field which is used for aggregate function and an empty row is displayed(where an aggregate function result had displayed).Demo Gif

An aggregate function is configured for two fields(Course and Departement).While grouping Department and Course ,average percentage of marks and maximum pass percentage has to be displayed respectively.Departement field is grouped inside Departement field ,FacultyCount(field without aggregate function configuration) field is grouped,after that Course field is grouped.After grouping all these field ,aggregate function result display is not clear for end user.Demo Image.


Expected Behaviour : Need to remove an empty row while the aggregate function configured field is hidden and need clarity while displaying aggregate function for multiple field.
Kindly provide the solution for this issue in the slickgrid.
Software Version
Angular: 15.2.9
Angular-Slickgrid : 4.3.1
TypeScript: 5.3.3
Operating System: Windows 11 Pro
Node: 18.19.0
NPM: 10.2.3
Need to remove an empty row while the aggregate function configured field is hidden and need clarity while displaying aggregate function for multiple fields
